# Error comparing string from UserDefaults with a Bool

Tags: swift

I want that the first time I login something like a tutorial will appear.

But it says:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'Bool'

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let checkForFirstTimeLaunch = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Flag")

    if checkForFirstTimeLaunch == false {
        print("First time launch")

        //if user launches app for the first time, it will go here
        let PageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! PageViewController

        self.present(PageViewController, animated: true)
    } else {
        //otherwise, it will go here
        let HomeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

        self.present(HomeViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `UserDefaults.standard.STRING(forKey:...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others you can only compare `String` - `String` or `Bool` - `Bool`. In this case - for a flag - a `Bool` is preferable

Further you have to save `true` after the user has launched the app the first time.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let checkForFirstTimeLaunch = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Flag") // default is false

    if checkForFirstTimeLaunch == false {
        print("First time launch")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Flag") // save `true` to go to the else branch the next time
        //if user launches app for the first time, it will go here
        let PageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! PageViewController

        self.present(PageViewController, animated: true)
    } else {
        //otherwise, it will go here
        let HomeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

        self.present(HomeViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

However from logic perspective *FirstTimeLaunch* is supposed to be **`true`** by default. In this case register the key-value pair before being used. The registered default value is considered until it changes:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.register(defaults: ["firstLaunch" : true])

    let isFirstLaunch = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstLaunch")

    if isFirstLaunch {
        print("First time launch")
        userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "firstLaunch") // save `false` to go to the else branch the next time
        //if user launches app for the first time, it will go here
        let PageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! PageViewController

        self.present(PageViewController, animated: true)
    } else {
        //otherwise, it will go here
        let HomeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

        self.present(HomeViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks it worked.
I Wanted that a tutorial should appear after being the first time at the Home screen after the Login.
But now the Home screen doesnt work... when im there the app crashed

Comment: That's another question. Check the class name and the identifier

Answer (score 0):

use this method for app firsttime launch 
func isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()->Bool{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

```
if let isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce = defaults.stringForKey("isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"){
    println("App already launched")
    return true
}else{
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce")
    println("App launched first time")
    return false
}
```

}